# appending contents to a div element on loading a page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get, load

I want to append the html contents receiver back from the sever (server 2) to the body of the current page (which I received from sever 1). This I want to achieve while loading the page (received from server 1).( Hence I am getting the original contents from two different servers.)

I tried using

```
function Faulttest() {var myarray=new Array();
    var urlarray=new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get({
     url:"http://csce.unl.edu:8080/Anomalies/index.jsp",
     data: "html",
     success:  function(result) {
     alert(result);
     $('#body').append(result) // result will be the contents received from the server
     },
     dataType:"text/html"
    });
});
// more contents   
}
```

The HTML contents of the page are:

```
<body style="font-size:62.5%;" onload="Faulttest();" >
<div id="body" >
        <h1>content top </h1>
       //HTML CONTENTS GOES HERE
</div>
```

Comment: this is cross domain activity. use `dataType:jsonp`,  for more info read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Not really related to your question (not that you actually asked a question, you just made a series of statements), but there's no point having a document ready function _inside_ an onload function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to load a page from a different domain. [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is going to give you trouble with that .You can't do that !

If the file you trying to load content from is in the same domain, you can do it easily by calling the jQuery `get` method.

```
$(function(){
  $.get("somepageInyourdomain.html",function(data){
       $('#body').append(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't `.load()` overwrite the current contents of the element? OP needs to append...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Ah ! Did nt notice that. Corrected with get method. Thanks

Comment: @Shyju thanks for the answer. I have done the ajax calls before also to different domain but mostly they were on some event. Does making the call to different domains on loads make a difference.

Comment: @Judy : You may consider using an iframe and set the src value of that.

Comment: @Judy - onload is also an event. But no, whether you do the Ajax call inside an event handler or not shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're confusing [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), as you're using the syntax for `$.ajax`, and it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    Faulttest();

    function Faulttest() {
        var myarray=new Array();
        var urlarray=new Array();

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://csce.unl.edu:8080/Anomalies/index.jsp",
            data: "html",
            dataType:"text/html",
            success:  function(result) {
                $('#body').append(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also diEcho is right, normally you can't do a cross domain ajax request because of security limitations, but there are certain hacks.
Using datatype jsonp will allow you to make cross domain requests, but then of course the service should return the result in json and support a callback etc.

And remove the onload function on the body tag, and run the function inside the document.ready statement to make sure jQuery is loaded.

Comment: A datatype of json doesn't allow cross domain requests. (And moving the document ready that was inside the `Faulttest()` function to put it around the function doesn't help since the function is no longer global and thus no longer reachable from the the `onload=` attribute.)

Comment: @nnnnnn - you are of course right, only jsonp allows cross domain request, edited it.